# Trying to build Excel RTD server in Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, com, rtd

I'm trying to build an RTD server for Excel in Delphi and I cannot get this part of the code to work:

```
function TRtdServer.RefreshData(var TopicCount: Integer): PSafeArray;
//Called when Excel is requesting a refresh on topics. RefreshData will be called
//after an UpdateNotify has been issued by the server. This event should:
//- supply a value for TopicCount (number of topics to update)
//- The data returned to Excel is an Object containing a two-dimensional array.
//  The first dimension represents the list of topic IDs.
//  The second dimension represents the values associated with the topic IDs.
var
  Data : OleVariant;
begin
   //Create an array to return the topics and their values
   //note:The Bounds parameter must contain an even number of values, where each pair of values specifies the upper and lower bounds of one dimension of the array.
   Data:=VarArrayCreate([0, 1, 0, 0], VT_VARIANT);
   Data[0,0]:=MyTopicId;
   Data[1,0]:=GetTime();
   if Main.Form1.CheckBoxExtraInfo.Checked then Main.Form1.ListBoxInfo.Items.Add('Excel called RefreshData. Returning TopicId: '+IntToStr(Data[0,0])+' and Value: '+Data[1,0]);
   TopicCount:=1;
//   RefreshTimer.Enabled:=true;
   //Result:=PSafeArray(VarArrayAsPSafeArray(Data));
   Result:=PSafeArray(TVarData(Data).VArray);
end;
```

I'm not sure about this part:

```
Result:=PSafeArray(TVarData(Data).VArray);
```

But it could be any part of the code.
Excel just doesn't show any result in the cell containing the rtd() function call. I did manage to get a result into the cell the first time Excel calls my "ConnectData" function that simple returns a string instead of a PSafeArray (although the very first call to that function fails to produce a result (N/A). Only after changing the Topic in the RTD() call it displays a result (one time only))

I based the code on an example in C# from https://blog.learningtree.com/excel-creating-rtd-server-c/

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why the vote down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OleVariant` owns the data it holds, and will release that data when itself goes out of scope.  So you are returning an invalid `PSafeArray` pointer to Excel.  You need to either:

1. release ownership of the array pointer before returning it:

   ```
   function TRtdServer.RefreshData(var TopicCount: Integer): PSafeArray;
   var
     Data : OleVariant;
   begin
     ...
     Result := PSafeArray(TVarData(Data).VArray);
     TVarData(Data).VArray = nil; // <-- add this
   end;
   ```
2. use [`SafeArrayCopy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraycopy) to make a *copy* of the array, and then return the *copy*:

   ```
   uses
      ..., ActiveX;

   function TRtdServer.RefreshData(var TopicCount: Integer): PSafeArray;
   var
     Data : OleVariant;
   begin
     ...
     OleCheck(
       SafeArrayCopy(
         PSafeArray(TVarData(Data).VArray),
         Result
       )
     );
   end;
   ```

Comment: Wow, you are the best Remy! It works now. Not perfectly, (still gives me n/a at startup) but I'm getting there! Thanks!